# How modify Details view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css

Part of my strongly typed Details view created in asp.net mvc:

```
 <fieldset >
    <legend>Fields</legend>
    <p>
        ArticleNumber:
        <%= Html.Encode(Model.ArticleNumber) %>
    </p>
    <p>
        CalCertificateFile:
        <%= Html.Encode(Model.CalCertificateFile) %>
    </p>
 </fieldset>
```

I need modify this view to display data in two columns. Is this possible in CSS

Comment: It isn't very clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean:

```
ArticleNumber:        number
CalCertificateFile:   file
```

with data aligned as table, then no it is not possible unless you use JavaScript or modify your views to wrap separate data in span or other tags. If you mean

```
ArticleNumber: number
CalCertificateFile: file
```

that is data is not aligned, just add style="display: inline" to your p elements.

UPDATE: way #1

```
<p>
    <label>ArticleNumber:</label>
    <%= Html.Encode(Model.ArticleNumber) %>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
p label { width: 30%; }
```

Way #2:

```
<fieldset >
<legend>Fields</legend>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>ArticleNumber:</td>
    <td><%= Html.Encode(Model.ArticleNumber) %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>CalCertificateFile:</td>
    <td><%= Html.Encode(Model.CalCertificateFile) %></td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

I'm sure there're many more (and more correct) ways. What is so hard about modifying views?

Comment: I mean first case: data aligned as table but dont know how modify my views